# World rail / train routes database

Tags: database, routes

I'm looking for a database of rail routes, and this worldwide. Does anything exist ?

I found something defintely interesting there (http://www.hippomap.com/worldrail_en.html), but it's a map, do not give the routes.

Any ideas?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

http://nationalatlas.gov/mld/railrdl.html has US rail, possibly some non-US. Depends how detailed you want it, and whether it has to be continuous lines. Look up websites that discuss Microsoft Train Simulator (and others) - people there have searched for rail maps before and might have some useful links.

Comment: Thank yo very much. However, it's really dedicated to us and it's a map layer - so it's really hard to convert this on Database occurencies. I will have a look to Microsoft train simulator. Does anybody have any other idea?